# opening jar file with admin privilege

Tags: java, jar, admin

I am getting this exception when i open jar file using cmd:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.File (Access is denied)`
How can i open jar file with administrator privilege?
**Simply double clicking the jar file does not open the jar file.I am using win7 as OS.**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to run java from a command prompt but want admin privileges. In that case, right-click on the "command prompt" and choose "run as administrator", then you can

```
java -jar myprogram.jar
```

from the command prompt as before.

However do you really want to allow this program to edit your hosts file? I'd recommend you find out what it's trying to do and make the change manually if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run jar file with admin privileges from console or by double clicking, without explicitly executing it with admin rights Which is most obvious from user's point of view as he might just know how to click and not internal working. Then this is my post answering your quest in simple steps.
[Run Java file as Administrator with full privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037339/run-java-file-as-administrator-with-full-privileges/22110928#22110928)