# write java file to C drive access error

Tags: java

Hi how can I get rid of C drive access with java codes I can do this with manual but I want to do this with java codes

here is my code

```
File file=new File("C:\\Windows\\b.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {

            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("file not created and");
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And my exceptions

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
at tekrar.Write.main(Write.java:26)`
```

Comment: Why do you want to write to `C:\Windows`?

Comment: This is expected behavior.  If Windows just let any old program write to `C:\Windows`, then it would be even more prone to malware than it already is.

Answer (score 2):

you need to run the program as an administrator to edit the C:\Windows folder. this is a system folder that you **should** not access.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write anything in the system folder without administrator privileges in windows. As I understand you cannot request administrator access from within a Java program and you'll have to RUN the application in admin mode.
See this question for some tips: [Run Java file as Administrator with full privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037339/run-java-file-as-administrator-with-full-privileges)

P.S. Do you really need to write into the windows folder?