# how to run a batch file from java using administrator privileges?

Tags: java, file, batch-file, privileges, administrator

```
how to run a batch file from java using administrator privileges?
```

I am trying to do this.But code is not working.

```
String cmd = "runas /profile /user:Administrator /cmd.exe /C certutil -addstore ROOT  E:\\WORK\\UI\\DesktopRecorder\\userdata\\certgen\\X509CA\\ca\\new_ca.crt";

Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = run.exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037339/run-java-file-as-administrator-with-full-privileges

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shortcut to your bat file and make it run as administrator from Properties > Advanced,

Now that you created a shortcut to your bat file lets say its name is `example.bat` and its located on C drive, so it means that its full name is `c:\\example.bat.lnk`

In order to run this shortcut, you will need to run it using ProcessBuilder,
it should look like that:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c","c:\\example.bat.lnk");   
Process p = pb.start();
```

**It won't work using** `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();`

Comment: This will need to be surrounded with a try/catch block to account for IOExceptions in order to compile

Answer (score 0):

runas needs its main input parameter encapsulated in double quotes.  The kicker is that **cmd.exe does too**, if you are passing it a command string with spaces, so you will have to use escape characters for it to work on the windows command prompt:

```
runas /profile /user:Administrator "cmd.exe /C \"certutil -addstore ROOT  E:\\WORK\\UI\\DesktopRecorder\\userdata\\certgen\\X509CA\\ca\\new_ca.crt\""
```

You would then have to escape that entire string *again* for it to work in your java code:

```
String cmd = "runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe /C \\\"certutil -addstore ROOT  E:\\\\WORK\\\\UI\\\\DesktopRecorder\\\\userdata\\\\certgen\\\\X509CA\\\\ca\\\\new_ca.crt\\\"\"";
```

Sometimes in runas with a nested cmd call, you don't have to escape the backslash \ characters, so if that fails, you may want to try replacing the sequences of four backslashes with two.  Good luck!