# UnZip folder to Program File folder using Java

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to create a `Java` program that will unzip a folder into a certain folder within the `Program Files` Folder.

I'm using the 3rd party library `Zip4j` to unzip the folder. the following is the code i'm using.

```
    String source = "C:\\Users\\chris\\Desktop\\New folder.zip";
    String destination = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Test Folder";
    String password = "password";

    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
        if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
            zipFile.setPassword(password);
        }
        zipFile.extractAll(destination);
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

it works perfectly if I'm trying to unzip to a normal folder on the desktop. but once i try to unzip it to the program files i get the following `Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

I assume that my program needs admin rights to be able access the folder within the `Program Files` folder. Does anyone know how to do this?

Error log:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Test     Folder\New folder\New Text Document.txt (The system cannot find the path specified) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213) at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162) at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.UnzipEngine.getOutputStream(UnzipEngine.java:432) ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need admin rights to write to the program folder.
Open the administrator command line and execute from there.

Check here how to enable admin rights from java code: [[Run Java file as Administrator with full privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037339/run-java-file-as-administrator-with-full-privileges][1])

Answer (score 1):

Please try to check if the folder is accessible or exists. Also if you have permission to the folder. Then Try below code:

```
String source = "C:\\Users\\chris\\Desktop\\New folder.zip";
String destination = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Test Folder";
String password = "password";

try {
   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
   if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
       zipFile.setPassword(password);
   }
   File file = new File(destination);
   if (file.exists()) {
      zipFile.extractAll(destination);
   } else {
      System.out.println("Foolder not exists"+destination);
   }
} catch (ZipException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The folder does exist, as i created myself. but ya it seems to be a permission thing, as that exception is thrown when the code can't open the folder/file name represented on the pathname. I tried your code, but i got the same error as before.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Test Folder\New folder\New Text Document.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)


 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
 at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.UnzipEngine.getOutputStream(UnzipEngine.java:432)
 ... 7 more

Comment: did you get this exception with the new code i provided? pls try that. Also as you said if it is a permission thing try with permissions.

Comment: Ya i got that exception from the code you posted, i ran the jar file from cmd while running in admin and it still didn't work :(

Comment: this may seem like a noob question but why do i see " C:\Program Files (x86)\Test Folder\New folder\New Text Document.txt " in your logs, instead of "destination = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Test Folder"?

Comment: New folder is the name of the zipped folder, and within New folder is the blank text file called new Text Doc, they are the files i want to unzip into the program files folder and the errors states that they can't be written to the test folder. but it is destination = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Test Folder" inside my code.

Answer (score 1):

Restarted my pc, and re-ran the code from cmd and it worked fine :)