# How to kill a process that we started using exec in java {.exec("cmd /c"+command)}

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec, destroy

So, I have started a process in java using exec method in Runtime class. Now, how I invoked this is as follows.

```
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime(); 
Process p=null; 
String s="E:\\Softwares\\fiddler4setup.exe"; 
p=r.exec("cmd /c"+s);
```

Now, when I trying to destroy the process using p.destroy() method. Fiddler4setup.exe is still running. I have been searching ways to close this for like a week. Even here, there is no particular correct answer for this sort of problem. Please kindly help me with this.

Also, running the file directly is not working as it's displaying some 704 error I guess. Then, I saw this solution of using "cmd /c".

Thank you.

Comment: It should be possible to run a binary Exe directly without using cmd.exe... So I would first debug why that call did not work.

Comment: I have debugged it. As far as I know, this process cannot be terminated and the messaged stated was "Access is denied" when I tried this in cmd @GhostCat

Comment: @GhostCat , it stats an error that: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: There we go. So simply start your Java program with admin rights ; respectively ask your users to do so. Obviously elevation is nothing that any program could trigger itself.

Answer (score 1):

To kill your process you have to use :

```
Taskkill /IM YourProcess.exe /F
```

Or with PID

```
Taskkill /PID 26356 /F
```

So your program should look like this :

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("Taskkill /IM fiddler4setup.exe /F");
```

Note you can get the PID of your process using this command `tasklist` in your cmd, this will be better if you use PID to avoid all problem of path.

---

**EDIT**

There no clear way to run your script as administrator mode, there are some question here hope can gives you and idea :

[Run command prompt as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596599/run-command-prompt-as-administrator)
[Java: run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator)
[Run Java file as Administrator with full privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037339/run-java-file-as-administrator-with-full-privileges)

Comment: try without path, like i do, or search the PID of your task and kill it like i do @SunilSonu

Comment: I am getting the PID of fiddler4setup using tasklist and then using the above code, yet it's not working. @YCF_L

Comment: Does it work when you run that command on a shell directly? Instead of calling it from Java?

Comment: i try this with java and with cmd but with another process not with `fiddler4setup` and it work fine, i think it is the same logic @GhostCat or i'm wrong?

Comment: Even in shell, it says "Access is denied" @GhostCat

Comment: i try with name and with PID and it work perfectly both in cmd and java

Comment: aaahh then in this case you have to execute it in administrator mode @SunilSonu

Comment: @YCF_L Can you share the code, so that I can test it once.

Comment: @YCF_L It works well in administrator mode, but how to run taskkill command in administrator mode using java.

Comment: this is the problem now @SunilSonu let me make some research and when i find i will tell you, actually i don't have any idea how to run it in administrator mode

Comment: I guess you have to make sure that your Java program is initially invoked with admin privileges. You probably want to check right on startup if your Java code is running with admin rights.

Comment: yes @GhostCat this is a solution, i find also other solution, like create a script witch enable the admin mode but no clear way

Comment: @GhostCat Can you please give an example for that?

Comment: I am not aware of doing that programmatically. You would have to use "run as admin" when clicking your icon. Maybe you need a new question if you want to somehow make the Java program do that by itself.

Comment: @SunilSonu there are no clear way to run your script as administrator mode you can check my edit hope this links gives you an idea