# Looking for making sun.nio.fs library a public

Tags: java

Is it any way to get the sun.nio.fs library as a public library? in OpenJDK it is private. Especially I need WindowsSecurity class, but the whole thing looks very useful to me. Of cause I've looked in Google.

Comment: Why specifically do you need the utility of that specific class? What are you trying to achieve? Most of these 'platform specific' mechanisms are exposed by publically accessible wrapperclasses

Comment: That is the problem that I can not find a wrapper class. I need to connect to remote machine with administrative rights and copy all the files from there.

Comment: Can this Thread be of use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037339/run-java-file-as-administrator-with-full-privileges

Comment: This thread is very useful in the way as I defined the problem here, but I needed "in code" solution.

Comment: Ahh right, I thougt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29918826/5231001) provided an 'in code' solution. But if that doesn't suit your needs, you'll need to look further I'm afraid.

Comment: Actually I accidentally find the answer below. But I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is to use com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.Privilage class that wraps the same Win Kernel commands as WindowsSecurity class does.